# Unity Animator Ignoring "Higher" Layers

Tags: unity, animation, skeletal-animation, mecanim, animator

[image: Anmation Layers]

I have a rather rudimentary layer set up:

- Lower Body: no mask, full weight, override.
- Upper Body: upper body mask, full weight, override.  This works as intended.
- Standing Up: full body mask, full weight, override.  This doesn't visibly work at all despite inspector showing animation playing.  Character is fully upright, doing his walking/aiming thing as if Stand Up From Stomach isn't playing.

It appears it is only "partially" following the rule that "higher layers take priority."  The lower and upper body work fine, as intended, where upper body overwrites.  But the Standing Up layer should be overwriting both Lower Body and Upper Body, but it isn't.  It's being ignored altogether.

Any ideas why this basic set up is having such difficulties?  I haven't even gotten to the part of playing with the weights in script yet to make the Standing Up layer not override Lower Body and Upper Body once the character is upright...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a stupid mistake!

Don't forget to set the animation rig type to humanoid!

[image: Humanoid animation type]